# Getting started with terminal services (remote desktop services) and thin clients

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

I've got a Windows Server 2008 R2 box and I want to make it a RDS server and connect with thin clients. I don't want to do VDI with hyper-v, as this box is already virtualized. RDS is installed and I've installed an RDS CAL. I've browsed the Technet articles, but navigating technet is worthless. Can anyone point me to a concise get-me-started guide to terminal services/remote desktop services? If I can just get aimed in the right direction I can probably figure it out myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Windows Server 2008 Terminal Services Resource Kit**
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735625859](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735625859)

Not concise, but quite good.  Some resource kit books are more of a reference, but this is eminently readable.  Various topics are compared with the previous versions to provide context, and there are plenty of best practice recommendations so that you can get it right.

It is for 2008 R1, but after reading this you will be 95% there.

Comment: I was hoping to find something free, but that looks like a good book.